# Avoiding getting final '&' in Python regex when extracting url param

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've been testing a regex of mine. The goal is getting a concrete and named url parameter from a website for replacing it.

Now I almost achieved to get the parameter with this regex:

```
.website.com.+tag=(?P<tagvalue>.+&|.+\s)
```

This works fine when the tag is at the end but it gets the value for 'tag' with a trailing '&' like 'value&' when it's in the middle.

I want to get the value but not capturing the ampersand. I tried to extract the termination characters out of the named group like this:

```
.website.com.+tag=(?P<tagvalue>.+)&|\s
```

but this regex doesn't work. It always gets until end of line. I want:

1. Check if there is a '&' character . If it is, capturing the parameter value without '&'
2. If 1 is not true and there is **not** a '&' character, then capture the value until end of line (I think this until a \s, because I'm processing text and the url comes inside it).

You can test the regex with some test text here:

https://regex101.com/r/mWetmI/1

Comment: Why don't you simply use `[^&]+`?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Python has [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)

Comment: Try `.website.com.+tag=(?P<tagvalue>[^&\s]+)`. But like Mike said, you're better off using the `urlparse` library

Comment: in python 3 its called [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: @MikeScotty With a regex I can make the replacement in one line and I'm familiar with them. Also I don't import more modules.

Comment: @sshashank124 I'm using yours. If you make an answer, I'm accepting this as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that with the following regex:

```
.website.com.+tag=(?P<tagvalue>[^&\s]+)
```

This will capture the values for the tag up to but not including the next `&` or whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Try with lazy repetition:

```
.website.com.+tag=(?P<tagvalue>.+?)(:?\s|&)
```

https://regex101.com/r/mWetmI/2